# React fails to make build with default app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

React fails to make proper build, even with default app.
I ran commands `npx create-react-app my-app` then `npm run build`.
When I open index.html in /build, the site doesn't work and I get following logs:
[image]

Comment: Can you add dependencies from "package.json" please?

Answer (score 0):

You can just open a React (or Angular) build by clicking on the HTML file.
What you have to do is the following:

Install any static server module (i.e. serve):

```
npm install -g serve
```

In the root directory:

```
serve -s build
```

And then your app will be served.

It would be wise to do that before you deploy to any cloud storage or even your own server, but if you are 100% your app works, you can just deploy in on **[Vercel](https://vercel.com/)**, **[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)** or GitHub pages, they are free.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I did exactly as you said and the errors I am getting are those in the image I provided.

Comment: Is your app working on development mode?

Comment: Yup. The problem is only with build version.

Comment: Try to delete the build folder and generate it again. It may solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately. it did not. I've tried this several times with completely new app. I've also tried with React v17